# Nexus 10 + Cyanogenmod 13 with Android 6.0.1 + TWRP 2.8.7.0 ---> ADB Recovery device was not found

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, twrp

Hello to every Android lover.

I'm trying to "`Create Nandroid Backup w/Custom Recovery`" as shown on the attached pic called "2016-02-02_14-12-02.png" with the "`Nexus Root Toolkit 2.1.4`". The process starts without problems,but it stops when it reaches the Recovery Mode. In this stage,it is able to detects my device,as shown on the pic called "`2016-02-02_14-05-35.png`",but then the backup process doesn't start. I read a lot of tutorials and they said to check if there is a yellow mark on the "`Device Manager`" of my operatyng system "`Windows 10`". As shown on pic called "`2016-02-02_14-06-42.png`",everything works fine. I'm not sure that everything works fine,because the pic called "`2016-02-02_14-04-41.png`" shows the reason because the backup process can't continue. I suspect that "Windows 10" is responsable for this behaviour. Infact,as shown on the pic called "`2016-02-02_14-08-20.png`",everytime that I attach and detach the cable that connects the usb port of the tablet to the usb port of my PC,two windows appears and I think that they could interfere with the communication between the tablet and the PC,but I'm not sure. I have also tried to install the "`CWM recovery`" instead of the "`TWRP recovery`",but the first has been removed and the second one has been reinstalled and the problem is not fixed. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Attached pictures :

[image: 2016-02-02_14-04-41.png]

[image: 2016-02-02_14-05-35.png]

[image: 2016-02-02_14-06-42.png]

[image: 2016-02-02_14-08-20.png]

[image: 2016-02-02_14-12-02.png]

Comment: Is there a good reason you don't want to take nandroid backup of device manually, by booting into a custom recovery?

Comment: no. just want to understand why it doesn't work using this way. also because the nexus root toolkit is an handy tool. I like to use it.